# How to echo the ACF Google Maps address

Tags: php, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

PHP noob here... I'm trying to display the address of an ACF Google Maps Field.

I would think that the following code would display the address as: 123 Main Street, Charlotte, NC 28216, USA but nothing is returned.

```
<?php 
$map_location = get_field('location');
echo $map_location['location'];
?>
```

I was able to get this to work, but it ads a comma after the house number, and a period after the zip code, which looks kind of strange. ex. 123, Main Street, Charlotte, North Carolina, 28216.

```
<?php 
$map_location = get_field('location');
if( $map_location ) {

    // Loop over segments and construct HTML.
    $address = '';
    foreach( array('street_number', 'street_name', 'city', 'state', 'post_code') as $i => $k ) {
        if( isset( $map_location[ $k ] ) ) {
            $address .= sprintf( '<span class="segment-%s">%s</span>, ', $k, $map_location[ $k ] );
        }
    }

    // Trim trailing comma.
    $address = trim( $address, ', ' );

    // Display HTML.
    echo '<p>' . $address . '.</p>';
}
?>
```

Does anyone know how to echo the ACF Google Maps address as 123 Main Street, Charlotte, North Carolina, 28216?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable for the ',' delimiter that will change to a space when your location array key is 'streetnumber'

`print_r($location)` should output something like this:

```
Array
(
    [street_number] => 123
    [street_name] => Example Street
    [city] => Melbourne
    [state] => Victoria
    [post_code] => 3000
    [country] => Australia
)
```

The returned field data is an associative array.
Thus you might also output each element by its key like so:

```
echo $location['street_number'];
```

The modified output would be something like this:

```
if( $location ) {
    // Loop over segments and construct HTML.
    $address = '';
    
    $location_fields = array('street_number', 'street_name', 'city', 'state', 'post_code', 'country');
    
    foreach( $location_fields as $i => $k ) {
        $delimiter = ', ';
        if( isset( $location[ $k ] ) ) {
            // reset delimiter
            if($k=='street_number'){
                $delimiter = ' ';
            }
            $address .= sprintf( '<span class="segment-%s">%s</span>'.$delimiter, $k, $location[ $k ] );
        }
    }
    // Trim trailing comma.
    $address = trim( $address, ', ' );

    // Display HTML.
    echo '<p>' . $address . '.</p>';
}
```